# Track integration user activity

Tags: history-tracking, login-forensics

We're looking for an option to track the activity based in the entries from the Login History report for an integration user.

We're logging and tracking the source app, we have field tracking on in various fields, but we still have daily a couple of entries for the user.

Before going object by object or asking SF for the Event Log option ($), is there a way to search for last modified records (globally) using the UserID?

I've the login history report, it reads, for example, the user did login today at 9AM, so, how can I figure which record was "used" by the user at that reported time?